# IBM Connections 4.5: Community Ownership and Subcommunities

Tags: ibm-connections

A user of IBM Connections 4.5 must be member of the parent community before he/she can become member of a subcommunity.

Adding a member with role "owner" lets the new member be a Community owner (so that multiple users can be owner of a community).

I have found that adding a member to the parent community "as owner" will force ownership for all parent's subcommunities to this member (at least as far as this user is member of the subcommunity).

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the architects responsible for Communities.

> There is a reason for this which is that that a Owner at a top-level,
>   means that the person has the full-lifecycle of operations available
>   to them, including setting owner on any subcommunity.  Adding them to
>   the subcommunities automatically is so that there are no-orphaned
>   communities.

*I hope this helps.*

Comment: After IBM SBT SDK 1.1.0 fixed some issues on sub community handling and IC5 extended the functionality of sub communities I cannot see anymore why this should be a good rationale. A new "owner" member of a parent community should be a new "owner" member of that community. Period. All present sub communities should stay untouched. -- Another topic is removing a member from a parent community. That operation should check if there are sub communities which would become orphaned after such operation, and deny it with a reasonable error message.

Comment: This request would concern IBM Connections. Where can I submit enhancement requests for IBM Connections?

Comment: The PMR/SPR process using IBM Support, or if you know a product manager, you can ask them to submit an enhancement.